# RecyclerView not displayed after changing fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have the following situation: an activity with three fragments that I switch between them, in the fragment A for example I fetch some data, save it into an array and I set a recycler view using that array. Then I go to some other fragment, B, and when turning back to A the recycler view is not displayed anymore. 
How can I solve this situation? I tried to put in the onResume method of the fragment mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but it didn't worked.

How I swap the fragments:

```
mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.navigation_home:

                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_search:

                    setFragment(searchFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_notifications:

                    setFragment(notificationsFragment);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });

    private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: How are you adding these Fragments?

Comment: Do not use `replace()` or the Fragment will be destroyed. If you want to preserve your data, consider using a database and load the data into `RecyclerView` using that database.

Comment: Question edited 
@UmangBurman but still, I should load the data each time I access the fragment?

Comment: Edited @TheWanderer

Comment: Can you show `setFragment()` too please.

Comment: You're using `replace()` so you'll need to reload the data every time the Fragment displays.

Comment: `I should load the data each time I access the fragment?` Yes, Actually you should, If you want to avoid that, you can use a `Bundle` similar to an activity. But, it's not recommended. The best way I see is use a database.

Comment: I think the issue is because you are creating your `fragments` outside `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` and once `fragment` is replaced and you are not adding it to the `backStack` means that `fragment` is destroyed. But you still have instance of it and next time you are providing same instance. So I think solution is for example: `setFragment(new HomeFragment());` or whatever you called it. You need to re-create `fragments` inside `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.